# How can i insert UIView between UIWindow and all the views it has and will contain in Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

i have a music player in my project and i want to insert this music player bottom of application. Actually i'm insert it inside UIWindow perfectly but all views goes under this player and it blocks some buttons and table items.

Here is my UIWindow insert code :

```
        Generate.miniPlayer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        Generate.miniPlayer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.window!.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        Generate.miniPlayer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.window!.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        Generate.miniPlayer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.window!.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.window?.addSubview(Generate.miniPlayer)
        self.window?.bringSubviewToFront(Generate.miniPlayer)
```

Here is my result:

[image: This is the result]

Actually what i want:
[image: what i want]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When you add yourView to view then yourView will be front of your view. For example you have two view `firstView` and `secondView` you have to put like below if you want to add what you want.

```
view.addSubview(self.firstView)
view.addSubview(self.secondView)
```

then you have to give constraint like below :

```
self.secondView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 self.secondView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
 self.secondView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
 self.secondView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
 self.secondView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.firstView.bottomAnchor ).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's not what I wanted to ask. My problem is that the UIViewControllers stay under the view I added. This is because the project is already finished and then a generic music player was added under all UIViewControllers. As a result, I have several UIViewControllers and one music player. I don't want to extend the UIViewController and put it in it because there is already a music player and adding code to each page means a lot of extra code.